# DataGridView default error inside a new thread

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Really I don't know if my doing is correct programmatically or not so I hope to point me out.

I have a DataGridView C# showing data from linked MySQL database and some input boxes to help inserting data into the database and all goes alright, but when I decided to make inserting operation in a separate new thread I do the following inside add button:

```
private void AddToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     try{
        new thread(() =>{
           // insertion code goes here
           //to update DataGridView after inserting
           this.studentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.schoolDataSet.studentinfo);           
        }).start();
     }catch(exception ex){...}
}
```

so then a new dialog error is popping-up in each new insert operation and nothing saved, here is the error:
[image: DataGridView default error]

I thought the error maybe caused of `this` conflicting in `this.studentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.schoolDataSet.studentinfo);` I did correct it but the error still there.
Any suggestion could help me out and appreciated.

Comment: Debug your code. See where you get this error. Read [What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) And fix it.

Comment: I did debuged it the error showed when reaching to `this.studentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.schoolDataSet.studentinfo);` line so why I thought `this` conflict but that didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got it,
after hours of searching, reading, and trying I found that I should use `Invoke` to this specific line inside the thread `this.studentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.schoolDataSet.studentinfo);` 
so it becomes as following:
`this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.studentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.schoolDataSet.studentinfo);}));`

I think the error caused because this line calls some features from the main thread to update datagridview while new thread executing and programmatically there exists a `cross-thread operation exception` so modifying or editing GUI prevented except from main thread so an error arises from thread behavior! it's how I did understand that.
if I'm wrong please point me.